# Compare a value to each row in the database table

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

> Already solved. I just used `WHERE MONTH(due_date) = $month` in the SQL clause. Never knew it would just be like that. Thank you for all your answer!

We have a table called `bills`. We do not delete a bill even if it is paid already for record purposes.

So our goal is to only display `The Bills for this Month`. I have a `$cur_month = current month value`. I know how to extract the month value from a field using `MONTH()`, using a loop to run though the table, but when I try to `echo MONTH(date)` the value through out the displayed series is just the MONTH VALUE of the very first row. It seems it failed to get the MONTH VALUE of the other rows.

> Fixed code below

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM bill WHERE MONTH(due_date)=$month";
$bresult = mysql_query($query);

while($brow = mysql_fetch_array($bresult, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $bdata = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT MONTH(due_date) AS M FROM `bill`"));
    if($bdata['M'] == $month)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$brow['room_id']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$brow['tenant_id']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$brow['due_date']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }   
}
```

> `$month` there is the holder of the current month
>
> `$bdata['M']` there is the holder of the month extracted. We just displayed it to check.
>
> So if `extracted_month` is equls to `current_month` then `display bill`

I hope you can help me in this.

PS: Still an amateur. This is not yet an online website. We only need help for the purpose of having it work.

Comment: Why not use a WHERE-clause in your first SQL to only SELECT the bills of this month?

Comment: The loop should be done on the query `SELECT MONTH(due_date) AS M FROM `bill``  and a WHERE will help as Philip said

Comment: WHERE MONTH(due_date) = $month?. It doesn't seem to work. Nothing displayed or anything. Or crap. We haven't added a dummy bill for march ahahah. let me try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Use a WHERE statement in your first SQL to only fetch those rows from the table.

Like this:

```
$query = "SELECT *, MONTH(due_date) as M FROM bill WHERE MONTH(due_date)=" . $month;
$bresult = mysql_query($query);

while($brow = mysql_fetch_array($bresult, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$brow['M']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$brow['tenant_id']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$brow['due_date']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

2) I find it good practice to always check if the result object is created and if so, to check if it returned matches (with `mysql_num_rows($result)`). That way you can show an error if something goes wrong (most likely in the SQL statement) or show the user that there are no matches (bills in this case).

3) Try to use MYSQLI to connect to your database instead of MYSQL, since the latter is deprecated. (See: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php for an example.)

Answer (score 0):

Try solving this problem using SQL.

SELECT b.amount_paid 
FROM bills b
WHERE  MONTH(b.due_date) =  3

Using the result of this query you would have all of the amounts for this month.  Sum your result and you are done.